# Is hiding code inside null like this safe?

Tags: javascript, null

Can you get the key after it's injected?

```
var outside=[];

var NULL=(function(){
    var key='';
    console.log("Hi, I'm null!");
    window.injectkey=function(k){
        window.injectkey=null;
        key=k;
        return;
        };
    window.askmeforkey=function(){return "nope! I could use my key for stuff though...";}
    setTimeout(function(){
        outside.push("I still exist and can alter things outside but you can't see me!");
        console.log(outside);
        },1000);
    })();
NULL=null;
console.log('NULL=='+NULL); // prints NULL==null
```

After try

```
console.dir(NULL); // prints null

injectkey('xyz');
```

And again

```
injectkey('abc'); // Uncaught TypeError: injectkey is not a function(…)

askmeforkey() // nope
```

**Possible use:** (Say the key might be an encryption key thats not hard coded anywhere)

`injectkey` could be done many ways via some secure encrypted messaging

Comment: Define "safe". Regardless of whether it's "safe" by any given definition, it's pointless. The exact same thing can be achieved in almost exactly the same way without the `NULL` variable.

Comment: yes, I choose null because I like the sound of it! If my question was hiding things in false you would have also said that was pointless too! (negativity is more pointless)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder safe as in - Can you get/read/see/change/delete the key?

Comment: I think what t.j. Was trying to say was that you can write the exact same code without naming the function at all and the result would be the same. You can remove `var NULL=`

Comment: @Dekel: That is indeed what I meant. Ben, perhaps don't assume the worst of people?

Comment: Ok sorry @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I'm going to leave the `NULL=null;` part in there as I feel it shows anyone reading the code that I am intending that the cannot access it (kind of like when Facebook says STOP! when you open the console)

Comment: One could easily get the key by intercepting the injection. Please tell us what you really want to do, and what you are trying to safeguard against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is entirely private to the anonymous function. Note that there's no need for `NULL` here at all, this does the exact same thing:

```
var outside=[];

(function(){
    var key='';
    console.log("Hi, I'm null!");
    window.injectkey=function(k){
        window.injectkey=null;
        key=k;
        return;
        };
    window.askmeforkey=function(){return "nope! I could use my key for stuff though...";}
    setTimeout(function(){
        outside.push("I still exist and can alter things outside but you can't see me!");
        console.log(outside);
        },1000);
    })();
```

This is a common pattern for avoiding exposing variables more widely than is necessary.

Comment: So it is common! And there is no way to get the key?!

Comment: @BenMuircroft: None whatsoever, unless you do something expressly to make it available outside (for instance, as the return value of a function where you've exposed the function).

Comment: @BenMuircroft: Of course, *nothing* is private from the user. They can put a breakpoint on a line (say, in the timeout callback) and then examine `key` in the debugger. But no *code* can access `key` from outside that scoping function.

Comment: You should mention that this of course does expose the variables `injectkey` and `askmeforkey`. Also, it is unclear what "altering things" would mean, *that* certainly can be seen from outside.

Comment: true as I could not figure out what 'altering things' would be in a simple example where the key does nothing (it's just a string in this case). But as you pointed out when altering things do not expose the key... nor anywhere don't link the key to anything that can be output or seen by a debugger!